# Loop Variable inside a Formula Function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am looping thru a column in which i need to add one to the loop variable within the FORMULA
My problem is how to write the correct FORMULA to go to the next cell using the lrow variable

Attached is a snippet of my code

```
 Dim LastRow As Long
 For lrow = 1 To 20

 If Worksheets("cars").Range("P" & lrow) = "1" Then 

 Worksheets("cars").Range("a" & lrow).Formula = _
               "=RIGHT(h & lrow ,FIND(""."",h & lrow))"
```

How do i concatenate the lrow variable within the formula ? 
I have also tried `"=RIGHT("h" & lrow ,FIND(""."","h" & lrow))"`

Comment: One could also ask the question if you really need a formula? It's an extra calculation and can be done directly through vba if you just need the value.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes using `Replace()` can avoid a lot of concatenation and quote-balancing:

```
Worksheets("cars").Cells(lrow, "A").Formula = _
       Replace("=RIGHT(H<rw>,FIND(""."",H<rw>))", "<rw>", lrow)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build the string, inserting the variables where necessary.

```
Worksheets("cars").Range("a" & lrow).Formula = _
               "=RIGHT(h" & lrow & ",FIND(""."",h" & lrow & "))"
```

Note the extra quotation marks and (ampersands) that I have placed to expose the variable from the rest of the string.